# Cache.Session return null value

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, session, platform-cache

I have create small function to **store and retrieve the value inside static using session cache**. but i am unable to get the data which i have stored in session cache. I am not getting any error on retrieve or inserting but **Always return null value**. Any one can help me.

**Here is My platform Cache setting**

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

**Apex Controller :**

```
public class SessionCacheController {
    public  static String name {get;set;}
    public  static String check {get;set;}
    public  static String dummy {get;set;}
    private static final String KEY = 'Key';
    private static final String VALUE = 'Any value';

    //adding key,value pair to cache 
    public static void  setData()
    {      
        dummy='setData';
        Cache.Session.put('MyPackagePrefix.PlatformCache.myName', 'Nithesh K');             

        Cache.Partition partition = Cache.Session.getPartition('PlatformCache');
        partition.put(KEY, VALUE);                     
    }

    //retrieve value by key 
    public static void getData()
    {
        dummy='getData';
        Name=(String)Cache.Session.get('MyPackagePrefix.PlatformCache.myName');   
        system.debug('myName *** ' + Name); // return null

        Cache.Partition partition = Cache.Session.getPartition('PlatformCache');
        check = (String) partition.get(KEY);
        system.debug('check *** ' +  check); // return null
    }
}
```

**Visual force Page**

```
 <apex:page controller="SessionCacheController">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="pageSection">
        <apex:outputText >  My name {! Name  } </apex:outputText>   <br/>   
         <apex:outputText > Check Key {! check  } </apex:outputText>   <br/> 
         <apex:outputText > dummy {! dummy  } </apex:outputText>   <br/> 
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:commandButton value="setData" action="{!setData }" reRender="pageSection"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="getData" action="{!getData }" reRender="pageSection"/>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

> When i click setData() command-button, Value is added cache.session and getData() value is retrieve from cache.session and render in visual force page .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found answer for my question by Allocating space to Session Cache and Org Cache Allocation . I have forgot to change the value of  Session Cache Allocation and Org Cache Allocation from 0 to some other value. without that it is not working..

Above session cache code only works if your created new **Platform Cache**. 
If you don't know how create a Platform Cache, Follow below link one by one

[First Follow this link to activate Request Trial Capacity](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/platform_cache/units/platform_cache_get_started)

[Second Follow this link to create new platform cache](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/platform_cache/units/platform_cache_use)

If your finished with above two step then click on **edit** on **platform cache which your newly created**, **Change trail value 0 to 5 in Session Cache Allocation and Org Cache Allocation** and save it.

[image]

[How to use session cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_session_examples.htm)